# C# - Variable with 2 arguments, by string

Tags: c#, .net

How can i make variable/class or something like this:

```
Person["James"].age = 22;
Person["James"].name = "James Bond";

Person["John"].age = 18;
Person["John"].name = "John Hock";

string m = Person[James].name;
int l = Person[James].age;
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. You could create a class with a string indexer which returns a type that has `age` and `name` fields or properties... what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: What even is this notation?  Are you just asking how to make a class?  Have you tried walking through some introductory C# tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your person class:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Then you could use a dictionary which has their alias/nickname as the key:

```
var people = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
```

And use it like this:

```
var firstPerson = new Person("James Bond", 22);
var secondPerson = new Person("John Hock", 18);
people.Add("James", firstPerson);
people.Add("John", secondPerson);

// e.g. how to access the element via the nickname.
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(people["James"].Name);
```

Comment: Might also show how to access it, per the asker's example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting this?

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
Person James = new Person();
James.name = "James";
```

Although, you might be able to user indexers to achieve something similar to what you posted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

But, in my opinion, Id just throw Person objects into a List so you can use Linq to do `.Where(person => person.name == "someName");`

What if you have multiple Johns?

Hope this helps.